# React useState Not Updating on Axios Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend, response

I'm trying to update the number of likes on click after success response from the server and everything works well. However, the number of likes doesn't get updated and I need to refresh the page to see the updated value on the element.

```
function UserPage() {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    let {authTokens, user} = useContext(AuthContext)

    useEffect (()=>{
        const getData = async () => {
             const{data: ServerResponse} = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tweets/');
       
        
         setPosts(ServerResponse)
        }
        getData();
    }, [])




    const handleLike = (id)=>{

        let posts_list = posts

        const post_indx = posts_list.findIndex((post=> post.id==id))
        posts_list[post_indx].likes++
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + String(authTokens.access)
              },
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tweets/action/',
            data: {
              id: id,
              action:"like"
            }
          }).then(function(response){
              
            setPosts(posts_list)
           

          }

          )
        
    }
    const handleDelete=(id)=>{
       // console.log("hi")
    }

        return (


            <div>
                <NavBar className='navbar' />
                {user && <p>Hello {user.username}</p>}
            {
                posts.map(post=>(
                    <SingleTweet onDelete={() => handleDelete(post.id)} numLikes={post.likes} onLike={() => handleLike(post.id)} id={post.id} content={post.content}  />
                ))
            }
                            
            </div>

        );
    
}
```

Also, the SingleTweet component is as follows:

```
class SingleTweet extends Component {
    state = {  } 
    render() { 
        return (
            <div className='border'>
                <div className='id-ret'>
                <h3>{this.props.id}</h3>
                <button onClick={this.props.onLike} type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary me-1">Retweet</button>
                </div>
                <p>{this.props.content}</p>
                <div className='tweet-buttons'>
                <div>
                <button onClick={this.props.onLike} type="button" className="btn btn-primary me-1">{this.props.numLikes} Likes</button>
                <button onClick={this.props.onLike} type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary me-1">Unlike</button>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.props.onDelete} type="button" class="btn btn-danger me-2">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated

Comment: Can you the response you get?

Comment: Put console.log before setPosts to see what is in posts_list (maybe findIndex just returned null)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the response is a success. and the console.log shows exactly what is supposed to be updated, and usestate updates the posts. In a weird way, it seems that SingleTweet tag doesn't just re-render...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is an array. Since the object reference remains the same, React doesn't update the state thinking nothing has changed.

The reason it shows after page reload, is because you updated the same in the backend and backend returns the correct data on load which is a new object.

One way to solve your problem would be to do the following:

`setPosts([...posts_list])`

This will create a new array with the same data, causing the reference to change. Once the reference changes, React will know to update the state.